# Regex replace certain class names with JavaScript from a html document

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I am trying to remove all the class names that end with an underscore. So:

```
<div class="foo bar_ baz boo_ fa"> </div>
```

would output:

```
<div class="foo baz fa"> </div>
```

I am trying to do this in JavaScript and so far I can do it if the input only contains the string without other stuff:

````
```Node.js
var input = "foo bar_ baz boo_ fa";
input = input.replace(/(\w*[^ ])(?=_)(_)/g, "");
````

outputs:

```
foo  baz  fa
```

I am guessing that I am not using look ahead correctly. I wish I could something like:

`input = input.replace(/class\s*=\s*["'](\w*[^ ])(?=_)(_)/g, "");`

**Program's overall purpose:**

The purpose of the script is to read the html document and remove the "bad" class names from the whole document...

Comment: Why are you using lookahead at all?

Comment: I am not that good at regex, was just trying to find an easy way to match with an ending character, and the only way that I could come up with was with lookahead on an isolated piece of string. I guess I shouldn't use it then ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried `/[^\s]+_(?: +|$)/g` and it matches any classes ending with an underscore and all the trailing spaces (if there are any). This should work for your replace.

Edit:
Since your string is more complicated than I thought, try this.

```
//get our test string
var input = "<div style=\"crazy_omg nowai_    \" class = \"bar_ baz boo1_              fa fsfs_ joined_name joined-name  \"></div><input class= \"eh_\" CLASS ='WUT_ WINSD_ SKJDJASD_Jkzsd' class=ok_    bugs='existing' class=biiii_ /> <div class=fndjkdf /> <span style='color:red' class=jkndndfd_ /></span></div>",
//build our regular expressions
attrMatcher = /(?:class *= *[\'\"]{0,1})((?:[\w -](?!\w+=|\/))+)[\'\"]*/gi,
classMatcher = /[^\s]+_(?: +|$)/g;

//if we find a class, check it for errors
var result = input.replace(attrMatcher, function(full, capture){
    //remove errors and return
    return "class=\""+capture.replace(classMatcher, '') + "\"";
});
```

Fiddle of it in action: [click](http://jsfiddle.net/7ep3bbo1/)

I hope that helps.

Comment: Is there a way to make this less greedy because for example if the input is: `<div class="bar_ baz boo_ fa"></div>`, then the output becomes `<div baz fa"></div>`

Comment: I guess since there's no way to know what attributes may be in input or even if there will only be one input per check, you'd want to do something a bit more complicated. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Markus, class names can include underscores and hyphens as well. I'm not sure that regex will hold up.

Comment: Valid classes look like this `-?[_a-zA-Z]+[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*`, according to the CSS 2.1 Grammar (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/grammar.html#scanner)

Comment: Updated my answer with something I think will work no matter what the contents of `input` are like.