# Regex for replacing a specific HTML class name with a prefixed one

Tags: python, regex

In a huge collection of HTML files, I've got to prefix all occurrences of the class name "wrapper" to "prefixed-wrapper", so the snippet

```
<div class="someclass wrapper notarget-wrapper wrapper-notarget"><a id="wrapper" class="wrapper">The term wrapper may occur as text as well</a></div>
```

gets rewritten to

```
<div class="someclass prefixed-wrapper notarget-wrapper wrapper-notarget"><a id="wrapper" class="prefixed-wrapper">The term wrapper may occur as text as well</a></div>
```

Following this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27235982/regex-replace-certain-class-names-with-javascript-from-a-html-document#answer-27236133), I partially succeeded to replace the target class name:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re

snippet = '''<div class="someclass wrapper notarget-wrapper wrapper-notarget"><a id="wrapper" class="wrapper">The term wrapper may occur as text as well</a></div>'''

# building regular expressions
attrMatcher = r'''(?:class *= *[\\'\"]{0,1})((?:[\w -](?!\w+=|\/))+)[\'\"]*'''
classMatcher = r'''wrapper(?: +|$)'''

match = re.findall(pattern=attrMatcher, string=snippet, flags=re.I)

# defining replacement function
def replaceClassname(match_obj):
    if match_obj.group() is not None:
        targetclassname = re.sub(classMatcher, 'prefixed-wrapper', match_obj.group())
        return targetclassname

# pass replacement function to re.sub()
res_str = re.sub(attrMatcher, replaceClassname, snippet)
print(res_str)
```

But unfortunately, the output has (at least) two issues:

```
<div class="someclass prefixed-wrappernotarget-prefixed-wrapperwrapper-notarget"><a id="wrapper" class="wrapper">The term wrapper may occur as text as well</a></div>
```

Issue 1: class name `notarget-wrapper` should stay untouched, but gets replaced to `notarget-prefixed-wrapper`; also, spaces between multiple class names are lost.

Issue 2: the class name in `<a id="wrapper" class="wrapper">` should get prefixed, but it isn't.

The reason for the issue is a wrong regex for the class matcher. What do I have to alter in order to get the issues fixed?

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly suggest using an HTML parser tool (the one I've used most is [BeautifulSoup](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html?highlight=class#searching-by-css-class)) rather than trying to parse HTML with regex. Those are optimized for exactly the case of "find me the elements with this exact class".

Comment: Thanks, that's a very good suggestion, it just didn't occure to me to use a parser. But for some reason, I have to do it with regex (because I need the code in a bash script as well) — so I updated my question and narrowed its scope down to regex.